# Is using notations like “cluster F” or f*** acceptable?

Tags: discussion

A member is using implied swear words in their answers. Is this acceptable, because it’s not an actual swear word?

See recent question: Water Heater Help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's unnecessary and distracting and should be edited out.

Swearing and profanity is not professional and we're supposed to be a professional site.

Answer (score 1):

I am constantly reminded on the [English](https://english.stackexchange.com) language [stacks](https://ell.stackexchange.com) that SE has no particular barrier about those words.  On an English language stack question about profanity, I've cleverly averted saying the F-word straight-out (referentially, to answer their question)...  only to have a diamond replace it with the actual F-word.

However, I wholly agree with ChrisF. **This stack** is not about English, [writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com), or about-social-interactions stack (like [IPS](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com) or [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com)) So **we are unlikely to encounter a topical use of it**.

Comment: saying things that are offensive are not helpful when discussing means and methods for any topic...including home improvement. When you accept the use of the f-word, it’s just bad manners plus is not helpful. I agree with ChrisF and think it should be edited out. Why would you think home improvement is not about English or social interactions? It’s all about communicating...and it doesn’t need to be offensive. Aren’t we here to help the diy’er?

Comment: @LeeSam You DV'd me for discussng policies on other forums, as a path to agreeing with you.  Weren't you just complaining about unfair DVs?

Comment: I’m not complaining about DV’s, I’m complaining about using the f-word on this forum. I understand that some people will disagree with my answers, but using the f-word (on any stack exchange topic) is not useful and can be hurtful to many. While you seem to think it’s not the responsibility of SE to monitor such language. True?

Comment: False.  I don't "seem to think it" - it  is actually the case that use of the word is authorized on certain forums (thankfully, not this one).  I provided an anecdote where I attempted to avoid use of the F-word and they added it to my post for me. I think you are trying very hard to judge me harshly, and you are missing the mark, all due respect. How should this have been handled differently BY ME, THE PERSON YOU ARE DVing?  Are you saying I should claim that SE polices this, when that is not true?

Comment: @LeeSam I have edited my post to make more clear what happened, as perhaps you misunderstood me.  Is that better?